# Unknown delay happening in jQuery/JavaScript callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm getting a strange delay in some JavaScript callbacks.  I've tried this several different ways, and I get the same approximate 30 second delay.  I'm looking for some input.

Way #1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('html, body').animate({  
    scrollTop: $("#bottom").offset().top  
}, 60000, null, function() {  
    window.location = window.location;   
});
```

This is some code that I just copied out and started playing with.

I thought that the delay was strange, but something in the code that I am using.

Way #2:

```
$.scrollTo($("#bottom"), {
   duration: 60000, 
   onAfter:function(){     
       window.location = window.location;  
   }
});
```

This is code from the ariel flesler scrollto plugin.

Way #3:

```
$("#bottom").ScrollTo({
    duration: 60000,
    callback: function(){
        window.location = window.location;
    }
});
```

This uses another scroll library based on jQuery.

Unfortunately, in all of these, there is a delay of approximately 30 seconds or so.  I've tried some other ways, and no success with them either.  What I would like is to scroll from the top to the bottom of the screen, delay for approximately 10 seconds, and then reload the page.  Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you realize that "60000" is a full minute? Are you sure there's a 30 second delay? Your duration is so long that it will barely do anything every second.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('html, body').animate({  
        scrollTop: $(document).height()  
    }, 5000, function() {  
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location = window.location;
        }, 10000);            
    });  
});
```

5000 is the time it takes to scroll to the bottom of the page.

10000 is how long it's going to wait after it gets there to refresh.

Remember these are in milliseconds. So that's 5 seconds and 10 seconds respectively.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  I think the problem is that I want a really slow scroll, that is why the time is set so high.  I think the scroll finishes, and then that amount of time has to go off, plus the amount of time while the browser just sits there.  It is a variable size page which means it displays better with a lot of data as opposed to when there is very little in the page.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can modify the numbers in the code above to your liking. If the code worked for you, can you mark it as the answer?